# SQLite COUNT JOIN DISTINCT

Tags: android, sqlite, join, count

I'm sure this is a duplicate but I cannot find the answer:

**SQLITE** query issue

Tables:

- Client
- Order

Relation: **Client** has Many **Order**

Success condition:

*Obtain the number of clients with orders*

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(Client.id) AS count
  FROM Client
  INNER JOIN Order
    ON Order.id = Client.id
    AND Order.storeId = Client.storeId // This is because Clients have many stores
  WHERE
    AND Order.id IS NOT NULL
    AND Order.date BETWEEN '12-09-2016 16:00:00' AND '13-09-2016 16:00:00'
```

**Problem**

If Client 1, Store 1 has 3 **Orders** the query should return **1** because is the same client and the same store **BUT** is returning **3** meaning is not counting the clients with Orders but the orders themselves

Solution?
Keep in mind this is SQLite and is being used in Android 4.1.1 so some SQLite functions may not be available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner query gets all the clients with orders. The outer query counts those records

```
select count(*)
from
( 
      SELECT Client.id
      FROM Client
      INNER JOIN Order ON Order.id = Client.id
                      AND Order.storeId = Client.storeId
      WHERE Order.date BETWEEN '12-09-2016 16:00:00' AND '13-09-2016 16:00:00'
      GROUP BY Client.id
) tmp
```

a simpler version would be to count the number of **different** (`distinct`) clients

```
  SELECT count(distinct Client.id)
  FROM Client
  INNER JOIN Order ON Order.id = Client.id
                  AND Order.storeId = Client.storeId
  WHERE Order.date BETWEEN '12-09-2016 16:00:00' AND '13-09-2016 16:00:00'
```

Comment: I tried the second one just for simplicity and worked fine! :3